# How to select a single div and animate it and its related elements in jquery independent of others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have three elements with the same class in HTML and I applied some effects using jQuery to the ".tag" class and related classes like ".content", which are triggered on hovering over them. But hovering over just one of the "tag" classes triggers the animation in all three of the divs because they have the same class name. I want the animation to trigger only on the "tag" class that I hover over. I tried using $(this) instead of $(".tag") but the animations are not triggered on the related divs like "content" or "tag-arrow".  Here is my HTML, and JS code:

```js
        var quicker = 100;
        var quick = 250;
        var quickish = 500;

        //  mouse over
        $(".tag").hover(function() {

            $(".tag").stop().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                height: "200px",
                width: "250px",
                bottom: "13%"
            }, quick);

            $(".tag--arrow").stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, quick);

            $(".content").css({
                opacity: 0.0,
                visibility: "visible"
            }).delay(quick).animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, quicker);

            $(".bottom-row").css({
                opacity: 0.0,
                visibility: "visible"
            }).delay(quick).animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, quicker);


            //  mouse out
        }, function() {

            $(".tag").stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.5,
                height: "50px",
                width: "50px",
                bottom: "15%"
            }, quick);

            $(".tag--arrow").stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.5
            }, quick);

            $(".content").css({
                opacity: 1,
                visibility: "hidden"
            }).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, quick);

            $(".bottom-row").css({
                opacity: 1,
                visibility: "hidden"
            }).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, quick);
        });
```

```html
HTML
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
        <div class="grid" data-packery='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "gutter": 0, "percentPosition": true }'>
            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <h2>Rishikesh</h2>
                    <div class="tag--arrow"></div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="texxt">Our hostel</div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Description lorem ipsum lksd flksdf jfkdlskf.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a href="#">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <p>Add to Cart</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4" style="background: url('../bonfire/images/gallery/thumb/16.jpg');">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <h2>Agra</h2>
                <div class="tag--arrow"></div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="texxt">Our hostel</div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Description lorem ipsum lksd flksdf jfkdlskf.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a href="#">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <p>Add to Cart</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="background: url('../bonfire/images/gallery/thumb/15.jpg');">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <h2>Varanasi</h2>
                <div class="tag--arrow"></div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="texxt">Our hostel</div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Description lorem ipsum lksd flksdf jfkdlskf.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a href="#">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <p>Add to Cart</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use $this selector http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/

Comment: $(this) works but only for the ".tag" element. The rest of the adjoining elements do not animate. Using $(this).find() works for finding the children elements, but not for finding adjoining elements like ".tag-arrow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this use **parent()** and **find()** selectors for respective **this**

```js
        var quicker = 100;
        var quick = 250;
        var quickish = 500;

        //  mouse over
        $(".tag").hover(function() {

            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                height: "200px",
                width: "250px",
                bottom: "13%"
            }, quick);

            $(this).parent().stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, quick);

            $(this).find(".content").css({
                opacity: 0.0,
                visibility: "visible"
            }).delay(quick).animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, quicker);

            $(this).find(".bottom-row").css({
                opacity: 0.0,
                visibility: "visible"
            }).delay(quick).animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, quicker);


            //  mouse out
        }, function() {

            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.5,
                height: "50px",
                width: "50px",
                bottom: "15%"
            }, quick);

            $(this).parent().stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.5
            }, quick);

            $(this).find(".content").css({
                opacity: 1,
                visibility: "hidden"
            }).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, quick);

            $(this).find(".bottom-row").css({
                opacity: 1,
                visibility: "hidden"
            }).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, quick);
        });
```

```html
HTML
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
        <div class="grid" data-packery='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "gutter": 0, "percentPosition": true }'>
            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <h2>Rishikesh</h2>
                    <div class="tag--arrow"></div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="texxt">Our hostel</div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Description lorem ipsum lksd flksdf jfkdlskf.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a href="#">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <p>Add to Cart</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4" style="background: url('../bonfire/images/gallery/thumb/16.jpg');">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <h2>Agra</h2>
                <div class="tag--arrow"></div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="texxt">Our hostel</div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Description lorem ipsum lksd flksdf jfkdlskf.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a href="#">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <p>Add to Cart</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="background: url('../bonfire/images/gallery/thumb/15.jpg');">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <h2>Varanasi</h2>
                <div class="tag--arrow"></div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="texxt">Our hostel</div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Description lorem ipsum lksd flksdf jfkdlskf.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a href="#">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <p>Add to Cart</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works very well!! Except for one hitch. Replacing ".tag-arrow" with (this).parent didn't work because ".tag arrow" is not the parent of ".tag", it is just another element next to it. Any way to refer to a single instance of tag-arrow? Thanks by the way

Comment: @TusharMishra my bad i saw it as parent in case of tag-arrow you can use $(this).prev() to get the element it will return you the element see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q6naqvLL/

Comment: @TusharMishra PLease accept the answer if it solves your problem